# Problems checking for letters or 0, within a string.[JAVA]

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I am new to java, and have encountered a problem I can't seem to get around.

I am trying to make sure that there are no letters or 0's in a string full of numbers. If the string only contains numbers I want it to return true, and if there are letters or 0's in it I want it to return false.

Please note that I don't want anything too complex for me such as RegEx, so if you could keep it as basic as possible I would be very grateful.

ex. "123456789" = *true*, "98765x321" = *false*, "46813079" = *false*.

Here is my code thus far:

```
private static boolean isCorrectSyntax (String str){

    boolean trueCheck = false;
    int i = 0;
    char charCheck = str.charAt(i);

    if(str != null && str.length() == 9){

        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){

            if (Character.isLetter(charCheck) || charCheck <= 0){
                trueCheck = false;
                break;
            }
            else{
                trueCheck = true;
            }   
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but RegEx might look scary but they are really simple and easier to read. Search for a tut on youtube it's an eye opener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `charCheck` to true before looping through and only set it to false if necessary. Also, you only use one character throughout your entire loop. You need to set it to the next character each iteration of the loop, not one time before the loop starts.

```
boolean trueCheck = true;
int i;
char charCheck;

if (str != null && str.length() == 9) {

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        // get the current character
        charCheck = str.charAt(i);

        // if the character is a letter or 0
        // the check is false, so set the flag and stop checking
        if (Character.isLetter(charCheck) || charCheck == '0') {
            trueCheck = false;
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check for [indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) `0` first , if it evaluates to -1 , which means the string didn't contain a `0` ,  then try to [parseLong()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) the string and handle the `NumberFormatException`. If there is an exception, then your test fails .

If the number string is huge , you can go for [BigInteger()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29) , but I think it would be an overkill .

These are the pointers , you can develop your code around this.

Comment: Im not sure how I would phrase the indexOf() or, how I would use  the numberFormatException, can you use them in an example piece of code? Sorry, I'm just really knew to java hahaha.

Comment: indexOf() == -1 is the somewhat archaic way of doing it, use .contains() in java >=1.5.  They evaluate to the same bytecode, and the latter is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the following;

```
String str = "1234XX";        
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*[^1-9].*");
System.out.println(!(pattern.matcher(str).matches()));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: He asked for no regex.